# RewriteRule Apache .htaccess redirect to root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've got a domain, rewrite rule used there.
How can I redirect link: localhost/r/123 -> localhost/r.php?token=123
I've already tried that:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^r/([\d]+)$ r.php?token=$1 [R,L]
```

Looks like it works, but bootstrap won't to link, because the directory is localhost/**r**/{and_files_in_this_directory}

But I want to redirect it to localhost/{and_files_in_this_directory}   --- (without **r**)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, thank you!